# JavaFx 2 - Display color in ComboBox

Tags: colors, combobox, javafx-2, render

Following the Oracle's example for a ListView, I have been able to get a ComboBox color rendering a list of color

[image]

My problem is that once a color is selected, ComboBox display the string name while I would like to display the color itself, with or without the color name aside.

How to change this code in order to get the selected color displayed?

Thanks all.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class ProvaComboRendering extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<String>();

    cb.setPrefSize(150, 20);
    root.getChildren().add(cb);


    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "chocolate", "salmon", "gold", "coral", "darkorchid",
        "darkgoldenrod", "lightsalmon", "black", "rosybrown", "blue",
        "blueviolet", "brown");

  cb.setItems(data);

  cb.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>(){
      @Override
      public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list){
          return new ColorRectCell();
      }

  });
}
  static class ColorRectCell extends ListCell<String>{
      @Override
      public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
          super.updateItem(item, empty);
          Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(120,18);
          if(item != null){
              rect.setFill(Color.web(item));
              setGraphic(rect);
      }
  }
  }   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}         
}
```

**Edit:** Is it possibile to show a tooltip displaing the name of the color while the mouse pointer is over one of the color list?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ComboBox's button cell property. You can use the same cellfactory:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<String>();

    cb.setPrefSize(150, 20);
    root.getChildren().add(cb);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "chocolate", "salmon", "gold", "coral", "darkorchid",
            "darkgoldenrod", "lightsalmon", "black", "rosybrown", "blue",
            "blueviolet", "brown");

    cb.setItems(data);

    Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> factory = new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            return new ColorRectCell();
        }
    };

    cb.setCellFactory(factory);
    cb.setButtonCell(factory.call(null));

}
```

or define a new cell factory for button cell, like below which adds a tooltipablity :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<String>();

    cb.setPrefSize(150, 20);
    root.getChildren().add(cb);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "chocolate", "salmon", "gold", "coral", "darkorchid",
            "darkgoldenrod", "lightsalmon", "black", "rosybrown", "blue",
            "blueviolet", "brown");

    cb.setItems(data);

    Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> factory = new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            return new ColorRectCell();
        }
    };
    cb.setCellFactory(factory);

    Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> factoryTooltip = new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            return new ColorRectTooltipCell();
        }
    };
    cb.setButtonCell(factoryTooltip.call(null));

}


static class ColorRectTooltipCell extends ColorRectCell {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null) {
            Tooltip.install(this.getParent(), new Tooltip(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Albertoacepsut. See update according to your updated question.